# A variation on square-freeness of Euclid numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

As pointed out by [Jeppe Stig Nielsen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/70134/jeppe-stig-nielsen), my previous question [A question about numbers from Euclid's proof of infinitude of primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2199547/214353) actually can be viewed as a duplicate of [Are Euclid numbers squarefree?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/220162/214353)

I then thought - maybe a simplified version could be more accessible. Let us modify Euclid's argument for infinitude of primes like this. Having discovered some primes $p_1,...,p_n$, we look at $p_1\cdot...\cdot p_n+1$; all of its prime factors are new, $p_{n+1},...,p_{n+m}$; we then look at $p_1\cdot...\cdot p_{n+m}+1$, etc.

The point is that this procedure is equivalent to something simpler: define recurrently $N_1=2$ and $N_{n+1}=N_n(N_n-1)+1$. We obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
N_1&=2\\
N_2&=3\\
N_3&=7\\
N_4&=43\\
N_5&=1807=13\cdot139\\
N_6&=3263443\\
N_7&=10650056950807=547\cdot607\cdot1033\cdot31051\\
N_8&=113423713055421844361000443=29881\cdot67003\cdot9119521\cdot6212157481
\end{aligned}
$$
(by construction, every next number only contains new primes, not previously occurring on the list).

The question now is similar to that in the linked questions: are all these numbers squarefree? Are there any more primes in this list?

And an additional question: will all primes eventually occur as factors somewhere on the list?

Comment: Not all primes are in the list. $N_6 \mod 17 = 4, N_7 \mod 17 = 13$. From there on the modulus cycles through 4 and 13

Comment: @MichaelStocker Great idea! I checked other primes up to 71, the same applies to all of them - they generate quite short periods, the longest has 31 (length 9). Seems like if a prime $p$ does not appear until $p$th step it does not have any chance.