# a question on Euclid Numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime, numbers $E_n=p_1\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n+1$ are called Euclid numbers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid_number

It is not known if there are infinitely many primes among $E_n$'s.

The second open question is if all Euclid numbers are squarefree.
[Are Euclid numbers squarefree?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220162/are-euclid-numbers-squarefree)

Are any two distinct Euclid numbers relatively prime? Is this known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Check the notes [here](https://oeis.org/A006862).  The first example is $E_7$ and $E_{17}$...