# An open problem concerns primorials plus one having square factors. What about primorials squared plus one?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, prime-factorization, primorial

No primorial plus one has ever been found that has square factors. However, when I started looking at the square of primorials plus one, I found:

(23#)^2 + 1 = 29^2 * 53 * 1116604864937

I've only searched through 107# so far, but I haven't found any other examples of this happening. Has anyone researched this extensively for powers of primorials and/or have a compelling argument for or against any primorial plus one having a square factor? Thanks for your help :).

PS: The primes (below 107#) are the squares plus one of 2#, 3#, 7#, 11#, 19#, and 53#.

Comment: Your first sentence needs a link, e.g., [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220162/are-euclid-numbers-squarefree). It seems this is also part of your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, still new to math.stackexchange. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The link from @Dietrich Burde gives a heuristic argument for all the primorials plus one having a non-zero "chance" of having no square factors.  You can do something similar for the remaining squares of primorials plus one

Comment: A proof that this is the only case is probably out of reach. Are you content with a lower bound for a prime $p$ such that $p^2$ can divide a number of your form ?

Comment: If there is a prime number $p$ such that $p^2$ divides another number of your form , then $p\ge 10^5$.

Comment: Extended to $p\ge 10^6$

Comment: By the way, the primorials $p$#$-1$ seem to be all squarefree as well.

Comment: Are you also interested in larger primes of the form $p$#$^2+1$ ? The next occurs for $p=1571$